# Unable to execute bash scripts even as root?

Tags: linux, bash, centos, permission-denied

I have a weird problem, I cant execute bash script even as basic as:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "me"
```

I am saving it as a test.sh and then do chmod 755 test.sh and once run ./test.sh getting:

```
bash: ./test.sh: Permission denied
```

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: Are you writing it in a filesystem that is mounted noexec?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That can happen if you have mounted the file system with the "noexec" option. You should remove it.

Comment: Also, to know quickly if your filesystem has been mounted with the 'noexec' option, use: `mount`
And to remove the 'noexec' option, simply delete it from the list of options against the filesystem in the following file: `/etc/fstab`. Or alternatively [add](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=989973#p989973) the 'exec' option to the end of the options.

Comment: The `user` option can cause this issue, as well.  Removing it allowed me to execute the binary in question.

Comment: Another possible reason in Ubuntu can be the default file manager behavior. Go to `filemanager->edit->prefferences->behavior` and check `execute on double click`

Answer (score 21):

Script needs be executable. Use this:

```
chmod +x <script-name>
```

Comment: this does it for me `+1`

Comment: This duplicates another answer from several years back. It's probably a common beginner problem, but this particular instance of this answer shouldn't deserve more upvotes than the original, especially since the question already mentions the original OP had already made sure the permissions were correct.

Answer (score 3):

Although not directly pertinent to this particular thread; if a file has come form a Windows system there may be a CR/LF at the end of the line.  This would affect all lines in the file, including the initial execution line, and would not be visible if you are viewing the file.

```
$ ./test.sh 
-bash: ./test.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

To see this, you could cat -A the file:
    $ cat -A ./test.sh 
    #!/bin/bash^M$
    echo "me"^M$

To remove, use dos2unix.

Answer (score 1):

Try

> ls -la

to see the actual rights and ownership of the file. To see if the chmod command actually worked. You might want to change the ownership along with the mod of the file check : http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/fileowner.html

Answer (score 1):

Use  `chmod +x ./test.sh`
this should allow you to run it.

Comment: Decent idea, but the OP already noted that `chmod 755` didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Also, check to see if the directory/filesystem containing the script is nfs-mounted.  root won't run scripts from nfs-mounted locations.

Comment: Can you expound??

Answer (score 1):

In macOS this can occur if a com.apple.quarantine flag exists. If you see a @ suffix on the permissions after running a `ls -l` on the script's path, execute `ls -l@ *script_path*` to confirm. Then run a `xattred -d com.apple.quarantine *script_path*` to remove the quarantine flag.

Answer (score 0):

you need use `./test.sh` when you in the directory of that file,if you don't,try `PATH TO THE SCRIPT`.or you can copy it to some directory of `/data` and chmod it for shell,then do the above steeps.if you still fail,it's ok because i have a same problem,i just did it success for once time.

Comment: Op got a "permission denied" , not a path access problem

Comment: if you are root user and still have that problem,so your shell is broken.i know that because i couldn't execute many commands of the sh shell(similar to bash) even i tried as root and it said permission denied like your,i couldn't change the permission.then i tried to copy them to my directory in `/data`,change permission and i could use commands again.but when i try to execute the script,it's no such file or directory.

Comment: Then you probablyehad the `noexec` problem which is explained in several other answers here.

Answer (score -1):

For filesystems which are mounted with the `noexec` by default, for example NFS, explicitly adding `exec` **at the end** helps, even when options provided earlier in the list default imply `noexec` as well, e.g. the `user` option.

So if you have one of those options:

- `noexec`
- `user`

Change them to:

- `exec` or
- `user,exec`

It is important to place `exec` at the end. Just removing `noexec` may help in certain cases, but not in all, if you are using other options like `user` before.